# getting error code 998 Invalid access to memory location when trying to read from named pipe

Tags: c++, winapi, named-pipes

I created a named pipe using WCF and C#, and a client to connect to it so that I know that it is working correctly.  Now I'm trying to create a c++ client.  So far I have been able to get the name of the pipe, connect to it, and write some data to it.  When I try to read from it I'm getting `error code 998 Invalid access to memory location`.  Here is the code I'm using:

```
HANDLE hPipe = CreateFile(pipeName.c_str(), GENERIC_WRITE | GENERIC_READ, 2, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, NULL, NULL);
BOOL bWrite = WriteFile(hPipe, &message, size, &bytesWritten, NULL);
LPVOID buffer = 0;
DWORD bytesRead;
BOOL bRead = ReadFile(hPipe, buffer, 10, &bytesRead, NULL);
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: I send a **bad pointer** to the buffer for reading.
When I use a good buffer, the problem is solved. :) !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No memory has been allocated for `buffer`, it is currently a null pointer, and the code is requesting that 10 bytes of data be read into an array that does not exist. From [`ReadFile()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365467%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> lpBuffer [out]
>
> A pointer to the buffer that receives the data read from a file or device.

To rectify:

```
char buffer[10];
```